# footer goes up with parent div height 100%

Tags: html, css, templates

I found other posts here but none of them had an explanation of the problem. Here is a basic example of what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/p1e5krn6/.

HTML

```
     <nav>
         <ul>
             <li>About</li>
         </ul>
     </nav>
 </header>

 <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
     <div id="one">asdasd</div>
     <div id="two">asdasdasd</div>
 </div>

 <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

CSS
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    }

```
header,footer{ background:blue; }

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
}

#content {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 60%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#one, #two {
    height:100%;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I would really like to know is why that footer goes up like that. I know how to solve the problem, I could put the footer inside the content div but that would be semantically wrong. What I would like to have is not a solution but a reason that would explain me the behavior of that footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have given `100% height` to the div `#one` and `#two` along with 100% height to content. Logically if they are part of the content only, then why give then complete height as well. Removing that property from those two divs solves the problem. See the fiddle: "https://jsfiddle.net/p1e5krn6/1/"

Remove the following style:

```
#one, #two{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct but incomplete. It is a combination of the 100% height on the parents and multiple children elements and the overflow settings of the parent elements. What you are seeing is multiple children with a cumulative height greater than the parent element causing the content to overflow. As stated, it is corrected by either removing the `height:100%;` on the children elements or setting the parent element's `overflow` to `auto`, `hidden` or `scroll`.

Comment: @IMI you saved my life, I wasn't thinking to the overflow property

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p1e5krn6/4/)

```
*{
float:left;
   }
```